# Export dxf files for use in Sketchup

Tags: qgis, export, dxf, sketchup

the export to dxf seems like it worked, but Sketchup will not import it. I don't think this is a Sketchup issue, as Sketchup imports other dxf files just fine.

Comment: What type of geometry is in your DXF file you are exporting?

Comment: it's a simple shapefile of a few city blocks.

Comment: geometry = lines or points or polygons....

Comment: oh sorry, polygons.

Comment: I have been exporting contour lines from qgis in dxf-format and I have been able to open the dxf-file in Sketchup. I have used Sketchup version 6 (includes still dxf/dwg import) because I don't have the Pro version.